# Jenkins with Embeded Winstone Reverse Proxy Plugin (with http Header) using embeded winstone server

Tags: curl, jenkins, hudson, reverse-proxy, winston

I have successfully configured the Jenkins to use the SSO with the Ping Identity ( Ping Access ) by using the [Reverse Proxy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Reverse+Proxy+Auth+Plugin) (•  Header User Name: X-Forwarded-User) and authorizing the users through LDAP groups.
Everything works fine.

But the problem is the risk of header injection. I am using the embebed winstone server. Wasn't able to find the way to secure the backend from the risk of injection. Reverse proxy uses the HTTP headers for authentication.

As an example anyone can enter the systems from backend lets say on linux machine (with curl):

```
curl -k https://yourserver.domain-name.com:8081/whoAmI/ -H "X-Forwarded-User: ABCD786" -v
```

Your help will be appreciated. We are not using any Apache Server or web (HTTP) server. Have deployed the Jenkins with the embeded WinStone Server.

Comment: I see your concern, are you doing any other verification or sanitization of inputs?

Comment: The Reverse proxy doesn't provide too much option regarding the configuration for the Proxy Server. e.g. If we can configure the proxy server IP address where it can validate that the Jenkins is doing a hand shake only with the Proxy Server. Regarding the verification or sanitization of inputs I am putting authentication (SSO) and authorization mechanism (LDAP). I don't have any concern from the front end. The problem is Securing the back end as I mentioned by using the curl example. How I can achieve this. to me it looks like  a limitation in Jenkins. It can be my lack of knowledge as well.